# Positive Expectancy with Random Chance

Tags: probability

A conversation came up at work about positive expectancy. I am having difficulty getting the same answer as the guys so I am throwing the question out to you folks...  Any help is appreciated.

A game costs €50 to play. If you win you get €100. You get 52 chances to pick the Ace of hearts from a deck of cards. Every time you pick a card it is then returned to the deck and the deck is shuffled again. You pay the €50 once and you then have up to and including 52 tries to get the Ace of Hearts. Is there a positive expectancy on this game?

I worked it that you have a 1/52 chance of winning every time you pick a card. While you do get to pick 52 times your chance of winning is still 1/52 each time you play.

( 1/52 * 100 ) - ( 51/52 * 50) = (200 - 4750) {I used rounded 2% for 1/52 and rounded 98% for 51/52}

What do you folks think?

Comment: I'm not sure the rules are clear.  You can draw up to  $52$ times without paying again?

Comment: Edited for clarity. You pay the €50 once and you then have up to and including 52 tries to get the Ace of Hearts.

Comment: Fair enough.  I can't follow your calculation.  There's a $\frac {51}{52}$ probability of missing on any given trial, so there is a $\left( \frac {51}{52}\right)^{52}\sim .3643$ probability of missing on all $52$ trials.  Thus the expected payout is about $63.57$ which is, indeed, greater than $50$.

Comment: I have copy and pasted this from below: That is exactly the argument I have heard, but I am unable to work out the maths to get a percentage for (1/52)^52 which would be how may times you win. It should be ≈0.64

Comment: $\left(\frac 1{52}\right)^{52}$ represents the probability of getting the desired Ace $52$ times in a row.  That is effectively $0$ and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Darn. I understand now. Thank you very much lulu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fail each time with probability $51/52$. Since you return the card to the deck, the draws are independent so you fail all and lose the game with probability $(51/52)^{52} \approx 0.36$. Since you win with probability greater than one half, the odds are good for you.

Comment: That is exactly the argument I have heard, but I am unable to work out the maths to get a percentage for (1/52)^52 which would be how may times you win. It should be ≈0.64

Comment: $(1/52)^{52}$ is not the "number of times you win", it's the probability that you pick the Ace of hearts *every time*. What you care about is picking the Ace *at least once*. The $0.64$ is $1-0.36$.

Comment: Thank you Ethan. I understand now. Looked at it all wrong. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To clarify for OP. The expected return of the game is

$E[R] = 100 \cdot P(\text{win}) - 50$

Where the probability that you lose is

$P(\text{lose}) = (51/52)^{52}$

and the probability that you win is

$P(\text{win}) = 1 - P(\text{lose}) = 1 - (51/52)^{52}$

Hence

$E[R] = 100 \cdot P(\text{win}) - 50$

$E[R] = 100 \cdot (1 - (51/52)^{52}) - 50 \approx \$13.7$

So this is a fantastic game :)